# Dev-C++ output is partially missing, what happened?

Tags: dev-c++, windows-11

When I was compiling a C++ program using Dev-C++5.11, I encountered an issue with incomplete output.

The code is as follows：

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        cout << i << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the program to output these 100 numbers, but the program only shows 75~100, and when I drag the scrollbar up there are many empty rows, but the numbers 1~74 do not appear.
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHKFO.png)

The program runs on Windows11 and I can not find a solution.

Comment: Limited console buffer size? Try increasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cody Gray, I realize that the problem may caused by limited console buffer size.

I can't find the correct way to change the buffer size in Windows Terminal.
And I saw this artical [Command Prompt and Windows Powershell for Windows 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-and-windows-powershell-for-windows-11-6453ce98-da91-476f-8651-5c14d5777c20).

I followed the Solution 2, and in Windows Console Host, the program can output correctly.